# Wikitude - Cordova ERROR: Plugin 'WikitudePlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, wikitude

I'm using Wikitude to the use the Augmented Reality on my iOS Cordova project. When I load the application onto my iPad I get the following error

```
2015-02-24 12:48:19.252 hellocordova[603:68658] ERROR: Plugin 'WikitudePlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2015-02-24 12:48:19.253 hellocordova[603:68658] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "WikitudePlugin992907769",
  "WikitudePlugin",
  "isDeviceSupported",
      [
          "Geo"
      ]
   ]
```

My config.xml file shows the following for the WikitudePlugin

```
<feature name="WikitudePlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="WikitudePlugin" />
</feature>
```

In the plugins folder I have the following files added when I added the plugin via the command line.

[image]

I have changed the names from WikitudePlugin to WTWikitudePlugin in all combinations and still nothing.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Are you using the `cordova-CLI` to build this?

Comment: Yes I am, I have used the CLI to add all of my plugins and create the ios project